# Zend Framework url redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
<?php
 class PI_Controller_Plugin_AssetGrabber extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    /*
        The module name
    */
    $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
    /*
        This modules requires the user to be loggedin in order to see the web pages!
    */
    $loginRequiredModules = array('admin');

    if (in_array($moduleName,$loginRequiredModules)) {
        $adminLogin = new Zend_Session_Namespace('adminLogin');
        if (!isset($adminLogin->loggedin)) {
            /*--------------------------------------
               Here I want to redirect the user
            */
             $this->_redirect('/something');
        }
    }   
}
}
```

I'm trying to do a redirect `$this->_redirect('/something')` but doesn't work! Do you know how can I do a redirect in this case?

Best Regards,

Comment: What's the error message? Nothing? Simply don't redirect? You could try $this->_helper->redirector() too, or $this->_helper->gotoUrl() see more on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.redirector.basicusage.

Comment: I can't use those things in my plugin, because you can ONLY use `$this->_redirect` ..only if you extend the Zend_Controller_Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker` to get the redirect helper or do the redirect directly from the Request object.

See the examples given in

- [Redirect in Front Controller plugin Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357732/redirect-in-front-controller-plugin-zend)

Answer (score 7):

... rest of code

```
if (!isset($adminLogin->loggedin)) {
    $baseUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl();
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($baseUrl->baseUrl().'/something');
}
```

... rest of code

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
class AlternativeController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Redirector - defined for code completion
     *
     * @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector
     */
    protected $_redirector = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
    }

    public function myAction()
    {
        /* Some Awesome Code */

        $this->redirector('targetAction', 'targetController');
        return; //Never reached!
    }
}
```

You need to get the redirector helper, then you can define the targetAction and targetController with the redirector. That should do it.

Comment: In your code you can use `$this->_redirect` but If you look at my code  you will see that I'm wrting an Asset Plugin Controller.

Comment: Uffo you still need to get the helper regardless. You can also use `$this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/my-controller/my-action/param1/test/param2/test2');`

Comment: I don't get it, why I have to create a controller in order to use an helper, I want to use that helper in my plugin, not in my controller.

Comment: The controller was the example I gave, the method is identical for other purposes. Just go read the Framework manual at this point.