# Unit test for login action (PHPUnit + Zend Framework 1.11)

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, phpunit, assert

I am trying to test my login controller and this is what i have written so far:

```
public function testValidUserIsredirectedToIndex()
{

$this->dispatch('/index/logincra');
$this->resetResponse();
$this->request->setPost(array(
    'login' => 'aymeric',
    'password' => 'toto2016',
));
$this->request->setMethod('POST');
$this->assertRedirectTo('/index');
}
```

/index/logincra is the url i want to test, index is the name of my controller and logincra the name of my action which is:

```
 public function logincraAction()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); // Recupere les posts
            if(!empty($data['login']) && !empty($data['password'])){
                $oLdap = new Mediagong_Ldap_Connect($data['login'], $data['password']);
                $oLdap->setLogin($data['login']);
                $oLdap->setPassword($data['password']);
                $oLdap->getUserInfos();
                if($oLdap->isLoggin()){
                    $user = User::getUserByLogin($oLdap->getUserName());
                    if(!empty($user)){
                        if($user->is_cra){
                            $frontLogin = new Zend_Session_Namespace('front');
                            $frontLogin->user = $user->id_user;
                            $frontLogin->setExpirationSeconds(1800);
                            $this->_redirect('/index/');
                        }else{
                            $this->view->information = 'Vous n\'êtes pas autorisé à accéder à cette interface';                        
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->view->information = 'Compte CRA inactif, veuillez vous retourner vers Damien...';
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->view->information = 'Mauvais login ou mot de passe';      
                }
            }else{
                $this->view->information = 'Veuillez saisir tous les champs';
            }
        }    
    }
```

I would like to test if the user is correctly forwarded to the /index url if the login and password are correct ( for instance aymeric/toto2016).

So far i have the error:

> Failed asserting response redirects to "/index"

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at [Zend_test reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.test.phpunit.html). I suppose it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting an error... Your test is failing because the page is not redirecting as you intend.

See this question for how to redirect

[Zend Framework url redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433118/zend-framework-url-redirect)

Per the Zend Manual:

> Due to its nature the redirector action helper plugin issues a
>   redirect and then exits. Because you cannot test parts of an
>   application that issue exit calls Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
>   automatically disables the exit part of the redirector as it can cause
>   test behavior to differ from the real application. To ensure your
>   controllers can be properly tested, please make use of the redirector
>   when you need to redirect the user to a different page:

The line `$this->_redirect('/index/');` is causing you problems.

Comment: The syntax for " $this->assertRedirectTo('/index');" seems to be correct however ...i don't understand what's wrong ... What would you suggest ? 
Thanks

Comment: Check your action. There is nothing wrong with your test.  It is telling you that your action is not redirecting.  Your redirect code is not correct.  See the link to the question in my answer.

Comment: ANSWER :
$this->request->setMethod('POST')
              ->setPost(array(
                  'username' => 'foobar',
                  'password' => 'foobar'
              ));
        $this->dispatch('/user/login');
        $this->assertRedirectTo('/user/view');